# How to modify only one row at a time in Listview?

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

I am trying to figure out the solution for the following listed problem. I have  a `Listview` generated using `Simpleadapter`. When I click on a row  in the listview I want to make a Layout with an id `colorful` as visible. I am able to do this. But my problem starts here. When I click on another row say row number 5 the colorful layout is visible, but the layout is also visible for the previously clicked row too. What I want to do is make the layout colorful visible for only the clicked row (i.e it should be visible for only one row at a time i.e is currently clicked row and hidden for all the remaining rows) and the layout should get invisible for the previously clicked rows. I tried doing with `viewholder` but it doesn't help. My code snippet is below. Guide me step by step as I am very new to Android.

```
           final BaseAdapter k=new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),val,R.layout.mytaskdata,new String[]{"sname","heading","desc","id","path","receiver","sender"},new int[]{R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2,R.id.textView3,R.id.hide1,R.id.hide2,R.id.hide3,R.id.hide4})
      {

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView myname=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView mydes=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView mytopic=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            ImageView edit=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView03);
            sent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    RelativeLayout r=(RelativeLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.colorful);
                //  r.setVisibility(arg1.VISIBLE);
                    int temp=sent.getCheckedItemPosition();
                    Log.i("itemposition",""+temp);

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"pos"+arg2+"hii"+positionThatSaysHi,1000).show();
                    if(arg2!=positionThatSaysHi)
                    {
                        r.setVisibility(arg1.VISIBLE);
                        positionThatSaysHi = arg2;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        r.setVisibility(arg1.GONE);
                         notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest modifying the `OnClickListener` to just record the selected row, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. This will cause the ListView to redraw its items by calling the adapter. Therefore, you just need to check this value in `getView()` to determine whether the "colorful" view should be visible or not.

So the updated code would be something like:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView myname=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView mydes=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView mytopic=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    ImageView edit=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView03);

    RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.colorful)            
    r.setVisibility(position == positionThatSaysHi ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

    sent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            positionThatSaysHi = arg2;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

That way, you ensure that only one view will be highlighted (while also simplifying your code).

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of choice mode in ListView ( see [setChoiceMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setChoiceMode%28int%29)), and set it to CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE.

Use the selection state to toggle the visibility of your colorful layout. If possible, the easiest way to do this is to  have the colorful bits in a selector drawable, with selected=true. That way it will show automatically, and you don't have to worry about hiding and showing views.