# Unable to display a layout only on one row of a Listview in android

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have displayed a `ListView` using a `BaseAdapter`. I am trying to display a `Layout` when an `ImageView` is clicked on a particular row i.e when I click the imageview at row 1 the layout should only be visible on row 1 and not any other rows of the ListView. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690628/how-to-modify-only-one-row-at-a-time-in-listview) link, but I when I click a particular row the layout is visible on other rows as well. I have done the following coding. Can anyone help me out with this.

```
int prev=-1;
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View converView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row = converView;
    holder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (row == null) {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mybag_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv_mybag_name = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_mybag_name);
        holder.tv_prod_price = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_prod_price);
        holder.tv_mybag_size = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_mybag_size);
        holder.tv_delivery = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_delivery);
        holder.tv_mybag_price = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_mybag_price);
        holder.imv_mybag_img = (ImageView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.imv_mybag_img);
        holder.imv_bag_preferences = (ImageView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.imv_bag_preferences);
        holder.lnr_dropdwn = (LinearLayout) row
                .findViewById(R.id.lnr_dropdwn);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    Ion.with(holder.imv_mybag_img).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .load(arr_mybag.get(position).getMybag_img_url());
    holder.tv_mybag_name.setText(arr_mybag.get(position).getMybag_name());
    Log.i("product name in bag", arr_mybag.get(position).getMybag_name());
    holder.lnr_dropdwn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.imv_bag_preferences.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            holder.lnr_dropdwn
                    .setVisibility(position == prev ? View.VISIBLE
                            : View.GONE);
            prev = position;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_mybag_name, tv_prod_price, tv_mybag_size, tv_delivery,
            tv_mybag_price;
    ImageView imv_mybag_img, imv_bag_preferences;
    LinearLayout lnr_dropdwn;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `holder.lnr_dropdwn.setVisibility();` outside the `onClick()` to uhh reset the views each time.

Comment: @hypd09 I tried but it doesnt help

Comment: @Tiny are you trying to hide other row except selected row?

Comment: In my xml file I have put visibility=gone for `lnr_dropdwn` layout

Comment: No, within the adapter, set it to gone each time unless the view was clicked (position=prev).

Comment: @hypd09 I have written this line  ` holder.lnr_dropdwn
                    .setVisibility(position == prev ? View.VISIBLE
                            : View.GONE);` Is this ok?

Comment: Yes, that should have worked..

Comment: but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a boolean variable in your pojo class as

```
private boolean isClicked;
    public boolean isClicked() {
        return isClicked;
    }

    public void setIsClicked(boolean isClicked) {
        this.isClicked = isClicked;
    }
```

//Make this changes it getview

```
    if(isClicked())
    {

            holder.lnr_dropdwn
                    .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    `}
    else
    {

            holder.lnr_dropdwn
                    .setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }`
    holder.imv_bag_preferences.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

arr_mybag.get(position).setIsClicked(true);
```

notifydatasetchanged();

```
    }
});
```