# How to modify only one row at a time while using Customized ListView

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have used Customized `ListView` And not `ExtendedListView`. i have taken `relative layout` in order to show it as sub_list. By default i have set the visibilty of this `sub_list` relative layout as `GONE`. And on the click of any `listItem` that `relative layout`(by default set as gone) will appear on the screen respectively. But When I click on any of the rows the `sub_list` appear for each row simultaneously. What i want is that it should be shown only for one row at a time. I have already checked this similar [question]: [How to modify only one row at a time in Listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690628/how-to-modify-only-one-row-at-a-time-in-listview)  and modified my code but still i am unable to achieve my goal.

Here is my pieace of code:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Activity context;
ArrayList<String> s_date,c_number,d_ration,s_time,download_path,a_number,a_name,dt_number;
int flag=0,temp=1,position;
String mUrl;
int posview;
private int selectedIndex;
CustomAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> start_date, ArrayList<String> caller_number, ArrayList<String> duration,ArrayList<String> start_time, ArrayList<String> download_path, ArrayList<String> agent_number, ArrayList<String> agent_name,ArrayList<String> dt_num)
{

    this.context=context;
    this.s_date=start_date;
    this.c_number=caller_number;
    this.d_ration=duration;
    this.s_time=start_time;
    this.download_path=download_path;
    this.a_number=agent_number;
    this.a_name=agent_name;
    this.dt_number=dt_num;
    selectedIndex = -1;
}
public void setSelectedIndex(int ind)
{
    selectedIndex = ind;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return s_date.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

public View getView(final int pos, final View v, ViewGroup g)
{
    //LayoutInflater l=context.getLayoutInflater();
    //View rowView=l.inflate(R.layout.log_layout,null,true);

    posview=pos;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, g, false);


    TextView start_date = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.start_date);
    start_date.setText(s_date.get(pos));
    TextView caller_number = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.caller_number);
    caller_number.setText(c_number.get(pos));
    TextView duration = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.duration);
    duration.setText(d_ration.get(pos));
    TextView start_time = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.start_time);
    start_time.setText(s_time.get(pos));
    TextView agent_name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.agent_name);
    agent_name.setText(a_name.get(pos));
    TextView agent_number = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.agent_number);
    agent_number.setText(a_number.get(pos));
    TextView dt_numb=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.dt_number);
    dt_numb.setText("MHL No. -"+dt_number.get(pos));

    RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.sub_layout);
    r.setVisibility(position == posview ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            posview=pos;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    return row;

}

}
```

Previously my code was:

```
          row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {

            //setSelectedIndex(view.getId());
             RelativeLayout sub_list = (RelativeLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.sub_layout);
            sub_list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    });
```

I am getting all the data dynamically. This is how i'm using the adapter in `MainActivity`:

```
    CustomAdapter a=new CustomAdapter(MainScreen.this,start_date,caller_number,duration,start_time,download_path,agent_number,agent_name,dt_number);
    data_list.setAdapter(a);
```

In this `start_date` `caller_number` etc are arraylist.This is how i'm parsing data in `MainActivity`.

```
    JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONObject callLog = responseObject.getJSONObject("call_log");

                        Iterator<String> phoneNumbers = callLog.keys();


                        while (phoneNumbers.hasNext()) {
                            String number = phoneNumbers.next();
                           // Log.v("string number",number);
                            JSONObject numberLog = callLog.getJSONObject(number);
                            Iterator<String> callEntries = numberLog.keys();

                            while (callEntries.hasNext()) {
                                String entry = callEntries.next();

                                //Log.v("unique keys are",entry);
                                JSONObject entryObject = numberLog.getJSONObject(entry);
                                jsonArray.put(entryObject.getString("start_date"));
                                jsonArray.put(entryObject.getString("start_time"));
                                jsonArray.put(entryObject.getString("end_date"));
                                jsonArray.put(entryObject.getString("end_time"));
                                jsonArray.put(entryObject.getString("recording_path"));



                                String startDate = entryObject.getString("start_date");
                                start_date.add(startDate);
                                String startTime = entryObject.getString("start_time");
                                start_time.add(startTime);
                                String endDate = entryObject.getString("end_date");
                                String endTime = entryObject.getString("end_time");
                                String call_sdate = entryObject.getString("call_sdate");
                                String call_edate = entryObject.getString("call_edate");
                                String call_type = entryObject.getString("call_type");
                                String caller = entryObject.getString("caller");
                                caller_number.add(caller);
                                String duartion = entryObject.getString("duartion");
                                String call_duartion = entryObject.getString("call_duartion");
                                duration.add(call_duartion);
                                String dtmf = entryObject.getString("dtmf");
                                String dt_num = entryObject.getString("dt_number");
                                dt_number.add((dt_num));
                                String recording_path = entryObject.getString("recording_path");
                                download_path.add(recording_path);
                                String agent_mobile = entryObject.getString("agent_mobile");
                                agent_number.add(agent_mobile);
                                String a_name = entryObject.getString("agent_name");
                                agent_name.add(a_name);
```

Comment: `notifyItemChanged(position)`

Comment: you can achieve this easily with ExtendedListView. why don't you go with that? Do you have any specific reason?

Comment: I have tried the same with ExtendedListView But things not working out so i switched back to Customized List View. @Nas

Comment: I will post what i achieved with expandablelistview which is the same u need.

Comment: yes please @Nas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two variables :

```
 Map<Integer, View> lastExpanded = new HashMap<>();
    int lastExpandedPosition =-1;
```

Create a function in your adapter :

```
private void expand(int i, View layout){
        if(!lastExpanded.containsKey(i)){
            layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lastExpanded.put(i, layout);

            if(lastExpanded.containsKey(lastExpandedPosition)){
                expand(lastExpandedPosition, lastExpanded.get(lastExpandedPosition));
            }
            lastExpanded.remove(lastExpandedPosition);
            lastExpandedPosition = i;
            lastExpanded.put(lastExpandedPosition, layout);
        }else{
            layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lastExpandedPosition = -1;
            lastExpanded.remove(i);
        }
    }
```

now,

```
final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.b);
        layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                expand(i, layout);

            }
        });
```

Comment: I have used your code. But getting error. what is `i` in `expand(i, layout);`

Comment: 'i' is the position.. Use pos.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ArrayList which contents as your data while you click on the item.

```
public class DataModel{
 private String s_date,c_number,d_ration,s_time,download_path,a_number,a_name,dt_number;
private boolean isChildVisible;            
..... create it's setter and getter methods.
}
```

when itemclick is called that time you should update the flag of isChildVisible for that position.

```
public void setSelectedIndex(int ind)
{
   arrayListDataModel.get(ind).setIsChildVisible(true);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In your getview method :

```
   public View getView(final int pos, final View v, ViewGroup g)
    {
        ----your initialization code.    
        RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.sub_layout);
        r.setVisibility(arrayListDataModel.get(pos).isChildVisible() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
    setSelectedIndex(pos);

            }
        });
    return row;
}
```

parse the data with below code :

```
final ArrayList<DataModel> dataModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (callEntries.hasNext()) {
            DataModel  dataModel  = new DataModel();
            String entry = callEntries.next();

            //Log.v("unique keys are",entry);
            JSONObject entryObject = numberLog.getJSONObject(entry);
            jsonArray.put(entryObject.getString("start_date"));
            jsonArray.put(entryObject.getString("start_time"));
            jsonArray.put(entryObject.getString("end_date"));
            jsonArray.put(entryObject.getString("end_time"));
            jsonArray.put(entryObject.getString("recording_path"));


            String startDate = entryObject.getString("start_date");
            dataModel.setStartDate(startDate);
            String startTime = entryObject.getString("start_time");
            dataModel.setStartTime(startTime);
            ...... same as above for others fields

            dataModelList.add(dataModel);        

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. i'll try this code. what is arrayListDataModel ? is it object of DataModel class?

Comment: No it is the arraylist which contents your all data. you have passed the data individuality in adapter but best practice is that you should create on Pojo/Model class for it and pass it. so you can manage the data easily.

Comment: I have not used Pojo/model before. So can you suggest some links about that. will it solve my problem?

Comment: follow this link : https://javapages4all.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/sorting-an-arraylist-that-contains-pojo-class/

Comment: okk i'm getting all the data dynamlically from an api. here is code.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this easily with expandable listview and your adapter class should extend BaseExpandableListAdapter

in activity

```
private int lastExpandedPosition = -1;

expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                final int groupPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {

                expListView
                        .collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
            } else {
                expListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
            }

            return true;
        }
    });

    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (lastExpandedPosition != -1
                    && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
                expListView
                        .collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
            }
            lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please check edited question. i have shared full code related to my ListView. Do you still suggest i should use Expandable ListView. @Nas

Comment: what am getting is when u click on row it should expand/show the sub list/item of particular row. when you click another row the previous row will close and expand/show the current clicked item sub list/item. am right?

Comment: My current code is working fine without using Expandable List. Is it necessary to change the whole code to achieve what i have asked for?

Comment: its up to u. it already has all code that u need and no need to notify adapter. its simple and complex less when compare to ur code. its ur choice to decide.